# Loading Google Analytic's gtag.js using Webpack after everything else loads

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, google-analytics, gtag.js

If I load Google Analytics like they recommended, everything works:

```
<head>
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-123"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-123');
</script>
```

However, I want to load GA after everything else loads and runs. My project uses Webpack and React, so I wanted to use Webpack's dynamic imports after React mounts:

initGoogleAnalytics.js:

```
import { GA_ID } from 'settings';

export default () => {
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  window.gtag = (...args) => window.dataLayer.push(args);
  window.gtag('js', new Date());
  window.gtag('config', GA_ID);

  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    const script = window.document.createElement('script');
    script.async = 1;
    script.src = `https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=${GA_ID}`;
    const elem = window.document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    elem.parentNode.insertBefore(script, elem);
  }
};
```

Component:

```
componentDidMount() {
  initGoogleAnalytics();
}
```

However, this doesn't log anything. It also doesn't make any network requests, aside from loading `gtag/js`.

How can I load GA after React mounts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. Google Analytic's code was:

```
function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
```

I changed it to:

```
window.gtag = (...args) => dataLayer.push(args);
```

However, GA expects an `arguments` object because it uses `arguments.callee`.

Comment: I have tested this and the first code works, the second didn't.